# Define prefix root node for Jackson Serialization/Deserialization YAML document to POJO with Prefix

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I found https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml to deserialize/serialize YAML files. However, I'm having a hard time to deserialize/serialize the following:

- I want to define a prefix to the actual document to be parsed as a POJO. Similar to a subtree of the document.
- I want to define the POJO that represents the simple object representation instead of creating multiple objects.
- The Error "***Unrecognized field "spring" (class ConfigServerProperties), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "repos"])***" is shown. But I don't know how to represent the prefix "spring.cloud.config.server.git" to be the root element of the POJO.

## Document

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          repos:
            publisher:
              uri: 'https://github.company.com/toos/spring-cloud-config-publisher-config'
              cloneOnStart: true
              username: myuser
              password: password
              pullOnRequest: false
              differentProperty: My Value
            config_test_server_config: 
              uri: 'https://github.company.com/mdesales/config-test-server-config'
              cloneOnStart: true
              username: 226b4bb85aa131cd6393acee9c484ec426111d16
              password: ""
              completelyDifferentProp: this is a different one
```

For this document, the requirements are as follows:
* I want to define the prefix as "***spring.cloud.config.server.git***".
* I want to create a POJO that represents the object.

## POJO

I created the following POJOs to represent this.

- ConfigServerProperties: represents the top pojo containing the list of repos.
- ConfigServerOnboard: represents each of the elements of the document.

  - Each properties are stored in a map, so that we can add as many different properties as possible.

Each class is as follows:

```
public class ConfigServerProperties {

  private Map<String, ConfigServerOnboard> repos;

  public void setRepos(Map<String, ConfigServerOnboard> repos) {
    this.repos = repos;
  }

  public Map<String, ConfigServerOnboard> getRepos() {
    return this.repos;
  }
}
```

The second class is as follows:

```
public class ConfigServerOnboard {

  private Map<String, String> properties;

  public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
    return properties;
  }

  public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

}
```

## Deserialize

The deserialization strategy I tried is as follows:

```
  public static ConfigServerProperties parseProperties(File filePath)
      throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    JsonNodeFactory jsonNodeFactory = new JsonNodeFactory(false);
    jsonNodeFactory.textNode("spring.cloud.config");
    // tried to use this attempting to get the prefix
    mapper.setNodeFactory(jsonNodeFactory);
    ConfigServerProperties user = mapper.readValue(filePath, ConfigServerProperties.class);
    return user;
  }
```

## Error Returned

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "spring" (class com.company.platform.config.onboarding.files.config.model.ConfigServerProperties), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "repos"])
 at [Source: /tmp/config-server-onboards.yml; line: 3, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.company.platform.config.onboarding.files.config.model.ConfigServerProperties["spring"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1094)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1470)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1448)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2740)
    at com.company.platform.config.onboarding.files.config.model.ConfigServerProperties.parseProperties(ConfigServerProperties.java:37)
    at com.company.platform.config.onboarding.files.config.model.ConfigServerProperties.main(ConfigServerProperties.java:42)
```

## Edit 1: Looking for a possible SpringBoot Solution

I'm open to solutions using SpringBoot's ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.config.server.git"). That way, we could have the following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.config.server.git")
public class Configuration {

  private Map<String, Map<String, String>> repos = new LinkedHashMap<String, new HashMap<String, String>>();

  // getter/setter
}
```

## Questions

- How to set the root element of the document?
- Deserialization must read the document and produce instances of the POJOs.
- Serialization must produce the same document with updated values.

Comment: Discussing this feature with FastXML's Jackson project at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/issues/82#issuecomment-271988379.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to come up with the following:

- Create 6 classes, each of them with the property required for the prefix "spring.cloud.config.server.git"

  - SpringCloudConfigSpring.java
  - SpringCloudConfigCloud.java
  - SpringCloudConfigConfig.java
  - SpringCloudConfigServer.java
  - SpringCloudConfigGit.java
- The holder of all of them is SpringCloudConfigFile.java.

The holder and all the classes have a reference to the next property, which has a reference to the next, etc, with their own setter/getter methods as usual.

```
public class SpringCloudConfigSpring {

  private SpringCloudConfigCloud cloud;

  public SpringCloudConfigCloud getCloud() {
    return cloud;
  }

  public void setCloud(SpringCloudConfigCloud cloud) {
    this.cloud = cloud;
  }
}
```

- Implemented the representation of the map easily.

The last one I used the reference of a TreeMap to keep the keys sorted, another map to represent any property that may be added, without changing the representation.

```
public class SpringCloudConfigGit {

  TreeMap<String, Map<String, Object>> repos;

  public TreeMap<String, Map<String, Object>> getRepos() {
    return repos;
  }

  public void setRepos(TreeMap<String, Map<String, Object>> repos) {
    this.repos = repos;
  }

}
```

## Results

Creating the verification as follows:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    File config = new File("/tmp/config-server-onboards.yml");
    SpringCloudConfigFile props = ConfigServerProperties.parseProperties(config);
    props.getSpring().getCloud().getConfig().getServer().getGit().getRepos().forEach((appName, properties) -> {
      System.out.println("################## " + appName + " #######################3");
      System.out.println(properties);
      if (appName.equals("github_pages_reference")) {
        properties.put("name", "Marcello");
        properties.put("cloneOnStart", true);
      }
      System.out.println("");
    });

    saveProperties(new File(config.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile(), "updated-config-onboards.yml"), props);
  }
```

The output is as follows:

```
################## config_onboarding #######################3
{uri=https://github.company.com/servicesplatform-tools/spring-cloud-config-onboarding-config, cloneOnStart=true, username=226b4bb85aa131cd6393acee9c484ec426111d16, password=, pullOnRequest=false}

################## config_test_server_config #######################3
{uri=https://github.company.com/rlynch2/config-test-server-config, cloneOnStart=true, username=226b4bb85aa131cd6393acee9c484ec426111d16, password=, pullOnRequest=false}

################## github_pages_reference #######################3
{uri=https://github.company.com/servicesplatform-tools/spring-cloud-config-reference-service-config, cloneOnStart=true, username=226b4bb85aa131cd6393acee9c484ec426111d16, password=, pullOnRequest=false}
```

There are obvious improvements required:

- I'd like to have a solution with a single class;
- I'd like to have a an ObjetMapper method that specifies the "subtree" of the YAML object tree that I'd like to parse.
- Maybe a more sophisticated SpringBoot-like @ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.config.server.git") would help.
- Helper methods for loading and saving the state of these instances.

## Load Method

```
  public static SpringCloudConfigFile parseProperties(File filePath)
      throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    SpringCloudConfigFile file = mapper.readValue(filePath, SpringCloudConfigFile.class);
    return file;
  }
```

## Save Properties

```
  public static void saveProperties(File filePath, SpringCloudConfigFile file) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    mapper.writeValue(filePath, file);
  }
```

## File Saved

- It maintained the sorted keys as implemented.